# How to remove white color circular border in google devices like pixel

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, google-pixel

any one having idea how to make icon in google pixel without white border circular. I can see chrome icon doesn't have circular border. How to make it any help ?

You can see in screenshot google chrome icon looks full occupancy but other hightlighted icon doesn't.

[image: Screehshot of how icons looks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer here is step :

1. Go to tiapp.xml
2. Edit android->mainfest->application touple

Previously it was :

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.connectMobileTheme" >
```

After changed :

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.connectMobileTheme" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"  android:icon="@drawable/appicon" >
```

This will manipulate `/Projects/titanium/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml` file to apply.

For this you required to maintain icon inside `/Projects/titanium/platform/android/res/`

[image: Screenshot of file structure]

Maintain icon inside this folder.

Reference : 
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24659
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

Comment: another tutorial on how to create Adaptive Icons for Titanium can be foudn here: https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/android_adaptive_icons.md